# Knitr: opts_chunk$set() not working in Rscript command

Tags: r, knitr

I'm using knitr to create a markdown file from Rmd and I have the following option set at the top of my .Rmd script to hide all results and plots:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
opts_chunk$set(results="hide", fig.show="hide")
```
````

When I hit the Knit HTML button in RStudio, this works - I get output without the results and figures. But if I run from the command line:

```
Rscript -e 'knitr::knit("myfile.Rmd")'
```

It appears the `opts_chunk$set()` line isn't read, and I get results and plots in my .md output. I've worked around the problem by specifying these options in the Rscript command:

```
Rscript -e 'library(knitr); opts_chunk$set(results="hide", fig.show="hide"); knit("myfile.Rmd")'
```

But I'd rather keep all the options read from the file I'm using rather than specified at the command line. How do I get the options read in the .Rmd file when `knit`ing with Rscript at the command line?

Thanks.

Comment: Session info might help, what versions of RStudio, knitr, and R are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you need to add

```
library("knitr")
```

to the chunk (you might want to set `message=FALSE` in the chunk options for that chunk).

The problem is that when you do

```
Rscript -e 'knitr::knit("myfile.Rmd")'
```

you're not actually attaching the `knitr` package, which means it isn't in the search path for functions, which means that R can't find the `opts_chunk` object.

- Using `knitr::opts_chunk` might work too ...
- as you suggested, so does `Rscript -e 'library("knitr"); knit("myfile.Rmd")'`

When you click the button in RStudio, RStudio automatically loads `knitr` in the environment in which it runs `knit()`.

Comment: Awesome, that does it. Should have realized this. Thanks.