# There are no figures in the word and pdf outputs when using RStudio and opts_chunk$set(fig.align='center')

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

I was using RStudio (Version 0.98.932), created a RMarkdown document from templates, then added two lines of codes into document.

```
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(fig.align='center')
```

But I could get figures in the html outputs, but no figures in the word and pdf outputs. I am not sure whether this is a bug of RStudio and any mistakes in my document. Thanks for any suggestions.

This is the full document I used:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Test"
date: "Friday, July 04, 2014"
output: word_document
---

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(fig.align='center') 
summary(cars)
```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

I have generated three files from the same rmd file using RStudio button. There are no figures in the test.pdf and test.docx if following these links.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m4uj9syk0aio7gg/test.docx

https://www.dropbox.com/s/evqwos78z4jx521/test.html

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g37hcyemgxl8q9i/test.pdf

https://www.dropbox.com/s/10pr2dsu4etl6at/test.rmd

However, when I removed opts_chunk$set(fig.align='center') or set other parameters (e.g. echo=FALSE,message=FALSE), I could see figures in all outputs.

PS: I don't believe this is a duplicated question with [Knitr: opts_chunk$set() not working in Rscript command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694567/). This question show we should load package knitr when using Rscript. In my question, I use RStudio and load package knitr.

Comment: I guess `opts_chunk$set(fig.align='center')` should be move just before the plot is done. And according to this [comment](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/611#issuecomment-25046583), it won't work.

Comment: How is this `rstudio` related?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question. I could get figures in the html and pdf outputs, but not figures in the word output.

Comment: Apparently this is not a duplicate. It is not a problem about `library(knitr)` or `opts_chunk not found`. `fig.align` is known not to work with any output format except HTML: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/86 I guess I have to emit a warning message in knitr in this case.