# knitr not aligning figures to center in pdf output--alternatives?

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, rstudio

Using knitr to make pdfs, the figures don't show when using the `fig.align='center'` option:

```
require(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(fig.align='center')
```

OR

````
```{r chunkname, fig.align='center'}
...code that makes figure...
```
````

Either way, no figures come out on the pdf when pressing the knit PDF button. But I remove the `fig.align` option and the figures appear, left aligned.

Tried it with `fig_crop: false` in the YAML header, too, same results.

This hints at why it's not working: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/86 but it doesn't cover what to do instead if we need figures centered. I could just produce the plot as a png and import it with rmarkdown, but that is definitely not in the spirit of reproducible research!

Any ideas what to do?

```
## R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
## Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
## RStudio Version 0.98.1028
```

(This is *not* a duplicate of [Knitr: opts_chunk$set() not working in Rscript command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694567/knitr-opts-chunkset-not-working-in-rscript-command))

Comment: Works for me. Show us a reproducible example. What is your `knitr` version?

Comment: Yes, it is a known issue without a solution yet. As I said in that Github issue, I know how to solve it, but I have not yet tested my idea.

Answer (score 13):

This has been [fixed](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/3dd924955eb1ac850997734b1526db11af1f8ac0) in the [development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr) of **knitr**, which I plan to release to CRAN in the next few days, and the version will be 1.8 if everything goes well with CRAN maintainers.

The reason for the original failure to align figures is that when `fig.align` is specified, the HTML syntax for images will be used (i.e. `<img src=... style=... />`), and Pandoc is unable to convert this to LaTeX properly. **knitr** 1.8 will just use raw LaTeX syntax to write figures, which will be preserved during the conversion from Markdown to LaTeX due to its `raw_tex` extension.

Comment: note this requires the graphicx LaTeX package, which can be included as described here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211638/21118

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround (see comment by [Yihui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559676/yihui)) you could keep the .tex file and manually center the image:

```
\centering
\includegraphics[]{…}
```

Comment: Thanks, but we certainly want an automatic solution :) I'm working on this now.

Comment: I certainly agree (I also stumbled on this bug), but since it is unclear when to expect the fix (I can only rely on skilled coders like you) it might be nice to have an immediate solution.